# ReactJSL How to target a single element in a map function with a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Component that renders a list of elements using the map function. Each element is rendered with a delete and edit button. I have added the delete functionality, but I'm having problem with the edit one.

The functionality that I want is: click on edit item, replace H3 element (which is the title) with an input field and let the user update the name. I've tried replacing an element with another but this only works for the first element of the list, because I get the element with 'getElementById' I have tried doing it with querySelector, but that selects only the last element of the array.

I have no idea what to do. I know the issue is selecting the particular element at the right index. I use an id as a key but I don't know how to properly replace the html element. Any help will be vastly appreciated.

Here is where the map function renders the elements:

```
class Donut extends Component {

  render(){

  const {donuts, deleteDonut, editDonut} = this.props;
  const donutsList = donuts.map((donut) => {
    return <div key={donut.id} className="donut">
    <div className="name">
    <img src={donut.image} />
    <div id="donut-name">
      <h3 id="donut-title">{donut.name}</h3>
      <p>{donut.date}</p>
    </div>
      </div>  
      <div className="price">
        <p>{donut.price}</p>
        <img src="img/edit.png" id={donut.id} onClick={()=>{editDonut(donut.id)}} />
        <img src="img/delete.png" id={donut.id} onClick={() => {deleteDonut(donut.id)}} />
       </div>
      </div>
})
    return (
      <div>
        {donutsList}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Donut
```

Comment: Consider using `querySelectorAll`, which will return you a list of matched elements. ID's in HTML are meant to be unique, which is why `getElementById` returns a single DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid as much as possible directly manipulating DOM elements when you using React. In this case, you should use another approach:

- Add a field to this class's state: `editingDonutId`
- When you click in a donut, set the `editingDonutId` to corresponding id and when you finished it, reset the value.
- In render function, inside the `map`, do a condition render to check if current rendering donut has same id with `editingDonutId`, if true, we render an input instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using react, not jquery, so do not use getElementById, try react solution.
This is my solution:

```
class Donut extends Component {
    state = {
        donutsState: {}
    }
    setDonutState: (id, value) => {
        this.setState((preState) => {
            const predonutState = preState.donutsState[id] || {}
            return {
                donutsState: {
                    ...preState.donutsState,
                    [id]: {
                        ...predonutState,
                        ...value,
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
    getDonutState: (id) => this.state.donutsState[id] || {};
    render(){
        const {donuts, deleteDonut, editDonut} = this.props;
        const donutsList = donuts.map((donut) => {
            const donutState = this.getDonutState(donut.id)
            // when user input the name, save it in the state.
            const onChange = (e) => {
                this.setDonutState(donut.id, { value: e.target.value })
            }
            // when click edit, replace h3 with input.
            const onEdit = () => {
                this.setDonutState(donut.id, { eidt: true })
            }
            // when enter key, replace input with h3 and submit the name value.
            const onKeyDown = (e) => {
                if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                    this.setDonutState(donut.id, { eidt: false })
                    editDonut(donut.id, {
                        name: this.getDonutState(donut.id).value || donut.name,
                    })
                }
            }
            return (
                <div key={donut.id} className="donut">
                    <div className="name">
                        <img src={donut.image} />
                        <div id="donut-name">
                            {
                                donutState.edit
                                ? <input id="edit-donut-title" value={donutState.value || donut.name} onChange={onChange} onKeyDown={onKeyDown} />
                                : <h3 id="donut-title">{donut.name}</h3>
                            }
                            <h3 id="donut-title">{donut.name}</h3>
                            <p>{donut.date}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div className="price">
                        <p>{donut.price}</p>
                        <img src="img/edit.png" id={donut.id} onClick={()=>{editDonut(donut.id)}} />
                        <img src="img/delete.png" id={donut.id} onClick={() => {deleteDonut(donut.id)}} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div>
                {donutsList}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Donut
```